# API returns JSON object with results in an array, How to iterate through them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I'm trying to make a simple news feed app to practise working with API's. I've made a fetch request but I cant work out how to correctly iterate over the array. My objective is simply to be able to get the Author and title and output them to the page in html

**Javascript**

```
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
      'country=us&' +
      'apiKey=123DemoKey';
var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    })
```

**Snippet of Returned Data from API**

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 20,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": "cnn",
"name": "CNN"
},
"author": "Sheena McKenzie, CNN",
"title": "Russian spy attack: Customers urged to wash clothes as traces of nerve agent found",
"description": "Customers at a restaurant and pub in Salisbury were urged to wash their clothes Sunday, after traces of the nerve agent used on Russian spy Sergei Skripal and his daughter were detected.",
"url": "https://www.cnn.com/2018/03/11/europe/russian-spy-attack-customers-told-to-wash-clothes-intl/index.html",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180306183502-russian-spy-critically-ill-salisbury-uk-investigation-black-pkg-00005819-super-tease.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2018-03-11T13:07:01Z"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the JSON is a little confusing to me. Where does the `"articles"` array terminate? If you just want to iterate through Arrays, Sean Denny's answer is the way to do it and access the data by using `art.author`, `art.title`, etc. Or, you can use `Object.keys()` if you want to iterate through it all. You can display the data into your HTML by programmatically setting your elements from inside your `fetch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since News API returns JSON you can parse it as you did and then use `.forEach` or a `for...of` loop to iterate through the result.

```
fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines')
.then(r => r.json())
.then(r => {
    r.articles.forEach(art => {
        // ... do something with `art`
    });

    for (const art of r.articles) {
        // ... do something with `art`
    }
});
```

Comment: I also have a web app with this in action https://github.com/Nektro/apps.nektro.net/blob/master/src/news/app.js